# Condition where the result is empty in PHP

Tags: php

```
$output = "<loginsuccess>";

for( $i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++ )          {


$output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";
}

$output .= "</loginsuccess>";
```

I need now a simple condition where if the result is empty then i need to return no inside the xml [ login success ].

Is this a correct way....

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))          {

for( $i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++ )          {

$output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";
} } else { 
    $output.="no"; 
}
```

Comment: no, your method wouldn't work, because you'd skip the first result row in your for-loop (because you already requested it in the if-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$i = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";

    $i++;
}

if ($i == 1)
    $output .= "no";
```

Comment: are you serious? if $i==1? you forgot the `goto` somewhere.

Comment: Yes if $i == 1, the while loop never ran and the result is empty.

Comment: I don;t really see any problems with this, just make sure no code ends up between the $i=1, the while loop and the if($i==1).

Comment: Given the original code I was working on the assumption $i was used in the loop and had been chopped out for the Q.  If $i isn't needed then you could do it a bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { 
  $output .= '<loginsuccess>no</loginsuccess>';
} else {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note, I would do what Schnalle does, but in your code I would change the for loop to a while loop as you are not doing anything with the $i

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
```

In total I would write you code like this:

```
$output = '<loginsucces>';
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";
  }
} else {
  $output .= 'no';
}
$output .= '</loginsucces>';
```

Also It owuld be even better not to mix logic and output, but that would be overkill in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Wont the `for`-loop simply be skipped when there are no rows? Otherwise you might want to use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to count the number of rows in your result set.